# MariaDB Galera Cluster Replication

Tags: replication, mariadb, clustering, galera

Does the replication between an async slave connected to a master withing the cluster affect the performance of the master in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

As mysqld spawns a new thread per connected slave to dump binary logs, I do not think adding a slave would have significant impact on node's performance.